# Has the ID column configured as PK, NN and AI, be the first column on my table definition?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.6, table, alter-table

I have a `.csv` file with a bunch of data which I am using for load all the data into a DB table. The file lacks the ID column (because that's is an internal column managed through our software and they don't care about it).

To avoid issues with the data my "solution" was to move the column `id` to a position where doesn't interfere with the data from the file and that's right after `ActiveFlag` column or just at the end.

Check the following image for a graphical representation of the table:[image]

Currently the `id` is my first column and I haven't any problem but I am trying to move to the end because the issue I am having with the data but I got the following error:

```
Operation failed: 
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `sedb`.`volume_pricing_agreement` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER `ActiveFlag`,
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`AgreementNumber`,`CustomerSiteID`, `CFProgramLevelID`, `Source`, `AgreementTypeID`, `id`);

ERROR 1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

I don't know if the column has to be the first one on the table definition and if there is anyway to let it be wherever I want to or the solution maybe would be import the data by skipping the `id` column (supposing it's the first one).

I was checking the syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) but I don't have a clue in how to skip a column during load:

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
    [(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
    [SET col_name = expr,...]
```

This is the output of the command `SHOW CREATE TABLE sedb.volume_pricing_agreement;`:

```
volume_pricing_agreement, CREATE TABLE `volume_pricing_agreement` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AgreementNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AgreementName` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerSiteID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CFProgramLevelID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Discount` decimal(5,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `Source` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ActiveFlag` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `AgreementTypeID` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `AgreementNumber` (`AgreementNumber`),
  KEY `CustomerSiteID` (`CustomerSiteID`),
  KEY `ActiveFlag` (`ActiveFlag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2763 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Any help? How should I deal with this?

Comment: Provide the output of this statement please: `SHOW CREATE TABLE sedb.volume_pricing_agreement;`

Comment: @JehadKeriaki added to the OP ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The order of columns in a table definition does not matter, with one old exception.  In older versions the "first" `TIMESTAMP` column had a special default `DEFAULT` value.

It is not required to have an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  However it is (essentially) required that you have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  It smells like `AgreementNumber` would be such?  Keep in mind that a PK must be `UNIQUE` (a MySQL requirement).

As a side note, an A_I does not have to be the PK.  The only requirement is that it be the *first* column in *some* index.  And remember that a PK is a unique key is a key.

But, that is not your 'real' problem.  That is, you need to do `LOAD DATA` without the `id` being provided.

Plan A:  Load into another table, then copy it over.  When copying the data over, specify all the columns except the id; A_I will take care of the rest.

Plan B:  Use `LOAD DATA`, but specify all the columns *except* `id`.  Again `A_I` will take care of defaulting it correctly.

Other tips, while I have you on the line:

- `int(1)` is a 4-byte number; the `(1)` means nothing.  Perhaps you want a 1-byte `TINYINT`?
- Use `INT UNSIGNED` where appropriate
- Use datatypes smaller than `INT` where appropriate; look up `MEDIUMINT`, and again make it `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` if appropriate.
- Use `NOT NULL` when appropriate.
- Don't index flags; they won't be used.
- Learn about "composite" indexes.

**More**

If you choose to have a 6-column `UNIQUE` key that includes some `VARCHARs`, having an A_I is probably better than making that the PK.

A `UNIQUE KEY` is two things:  An index, and a uniqueness constraint.  You can use it for either or both.

A PK is a `UNIQUE KEY` that identifies the row.  It also is "clustered" with the data, making lookups more efficient than with a "secondary key" (any non-PK).

When the 'cardinality' of an indexed column is very low, such as for a flag, the Optimizer will dynamically look at the value you provide and see if less than 20% of the table has that value.  In this case, it will use the index; else it will not.  The "20%" varies with the phase of the moon.  The reason for eschewing the index is that using the index involves bouncing back and forth between the index's BTree and the data's BTree via the PK.  This can be slower than simply scanning the data, tossing 80% of the rows.  A secondary key is a BTree containing the indexed column(s) plus a copy of the PK.

Comment: A few things: `AgreementNumber` can't be the PK because I can repeat it and this is where my _solution_ comes up. What I did was create a `UNIQUE` IDX for all the columns considered as keys: `UNIQUE KEY `UQ_AGR` (`AgreementNumber`,`CustomerSiteID`,`CFProgramLevelID`,`AgreementName`,`Source`,`AgreementTypeID`)` that way I can keep the column `ID` wherever I want. I don't know if this is the proper solution and if it's not I would like to know why and have some examples for your Plan B which I don't know how to achieve

Comment: Last but not least I would like to have an explanation about this `Don't index flags; they won't be used` (I am sure you're right I just want to know why should not be used an index on a _BOOLEAN_ value)

Comment: I added to my Answer to address both of your comments.